# How to complete this proof

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $n$ be in $N$ and let $f:R$ to $R$ be defined by $f(x):=x^n$ for $0\leq x$ and $f(x):=0$ for $x<0$. For which values of n is $f'$ continues at 0? For which values of n if $f'$ differentiable at 0?

Here is my idea: if $n\leq -1$, then f is not continuous at 0 because f is undefined f or$x=0$. if $n=1$ then f is continuous at 1 not 0. If $n>1$ then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ is continues at o. How to prove that $3\leq n$, then $f'$ is differentiable at 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ are defined to be positive integers, so you don't have to worry about $n \leq 0$.

Before you can establish whether $f'$ is continuous or differentiable at $0$, you need to first check whether $f'$ even exists at $0$, that is, whether $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists. Since $f$ is defined piecewise, you need $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ (and both limits to exist.)

That will give you $f'(0)$. Your statement $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$ is only true for $x > 0$. For $x < 0$, $f'(x)=0$ since $f(x) = 0$. So you now have a piecewise function, continuous for $x < 0$ and $x > 0$, so you just have to check whether $\lim_{x \to 0^-}f'(x) = \lim_{x  \to 0^+}f'(x) = f'(0) $. If all of those things are equal, $f'(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

Next, if $f'(x)$ is continuous at $0$, you have $f'(x)$ written as a piecewise function, so to check that its derivative exists at $0$, just repeat the above process.